# Iphone UISearchBar disappears when enabled for multiple tables

Tags: ios, iphone, search

I am working on an iphone app.

I have eight tables in a view and only a single table has alpha = 1 at a time depending on which tab at the top of my view is clicked.  This works perfectly.  I have a search bar that looks through the tables and operates almost perfectly - there are some bugs that I am working on.  Currently, my biggest concern is that the first time I click a tab, my search bar appears at the top of the table but if I click away to another tab and then go back to the first tab, my searchbar never appears at the top again.  This is the code that I think is relevant.

```
- (IBAction) updateView {


  if (isMens) {
    if (isA) {
        self.curTbl = 0Table;

        0Table.alpha = 1;
        1Table.alpha = 0;
        2Table.alpha = 0;
        3Table.alpha = 0;

        4Table.alpha = 0;
        5Table.alpha = 0;
        6Table.alpha = 0;
        7Table.alpha = 0;
        self.0Table.tableHeaderView = searchBar;    


    } else if (isB) {
        self.curTbl = 1Table;

        0Table.alpha = 0;
        1Table.alpha = 1;
        2Table.alpha = 0;
        3Table.alpha = 0;

        4Table.alpha = 0;
        5Table.alpha = 0;
        6Table.alpha = 0;
        7Table.alpha = 0;
        self.1Table.tableHeaderView = searchBar;    

.
.
.
```

This method is called every time a tab is clicked.  The views update properly but as I said, the search bar is nowhere to be found on a already-clicked tab once I click on a tab that has not been clicked before.  It only goes to the latest clicked tab.

Any ideas?

Comment: 0Table is not a valid C identifier; I'm surprised your code compiles at all.

Comment: That was not my real table name - I just switched it in for the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what's happening is that the UITableView doesn't know that its subview has disappeared, so it assumes that it's still a subview and has been laid out correctly.

Try something like this:

```
if (isMens) {
  self.curTbl.tableHeaderView = nil
  if (isA) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so Much!! You saved the day